# Access to the path 'C:\xxx\yyy\zzz\abcd_20120309.pdf' is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net website and a C# console application (both developed in VS2010). Both upload files to our web server (Windows Server 2003/IIS 6.0). Users logging in to the website can then view and download these files.
This works fine in website. But when I try to download files uploaded by the console application, I get the error:

```
        UnauthorizedAccessException
        Access to the path 'C:\xxx\yyy\zzz\abcd_20120309.pdf' is denied.
```

I have already manually provided "Full Control" to NETWORK SERVICE account for that folder.

Why is Asp.Net code unable to access a folder created by the console application?

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think Network Service account is used by asp. There is a user that starts with IUSR_.. but I don't know the risks

Comment: @mslliviu that depends entirely on config, but indeed this could be the problem if ASP.NET is using the default ASP.NET accounts

Comment: Hi Marc, the ASP.Net is using default account as I have not added Impersonation tag in config file. Since my website is running on IIS 6.0, I believe the default user is NETWORK SERVICE. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi mslliviu....I tried granting Full Control to IUSR_xxx Internet Guest Account. This seems to have taken care of the error. But this is not the ideal solution as there are security risks involved. Any other solution for this?

Comment: You can set the application is IIS (at least in IIS7) to use different account to access file system and I don't think it needs full access just to download files, read should be enough. There is a Connect As.. button where you define your physicall application path, and there you can set another user

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide access to the folder for IIS_IUSRS (or something along this line).

AKA you need access for IIS.

Including access to everyone, doesnt include this user. So it must be done directly.

Network service will not suffice.

If IIS_IUSRS doesnt appear in the list, search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it matters in this case but one thing I have seen in the past is:

The application first saves the file in a temporary folder and then moves it to the target folder.

Sometimes, don't know the exact rules, the file access right follows the file in the move. i.e. the file ends up with the access rights for the temporary folder even in target folder.

Check the access rights on the file and see if it differs from the target folder.